# "did a bit of googling" vs. "googled a few times"

Tags: word-usage

[According to Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/google), the verb "google" means

> to search for something on the internet using the Google search engine (= computer program that finds information)

[From a post](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/256462/117396)

> I did a bit of **Googling** and I seemed to find the kind of articles you are looking for by using the word "tips".

I guess it means the author googled a few times, such as, [writing tips](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C5CHFA_enUS706US706&sxsrf=ALeKk03pLnyDJBdgIe0_d4KP-o07BSxBeQ%3A1596319889924&ei=keglX4mAOJPpmAWr15aYAQ&q=writing%20tips&oq=writing%20tips&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzIFCAAQsQMyBggAEAcQHjIGCAAQBxAeMgYIABAHEB4yBggAEAcQHjIICAAQBxAKEB4yBggAEAcQHjICCAAyBggAEAcQHjICCAA6BAgAEEc6BAgAEEM6BwgAELEDEEM6BQguELEDOgsILhCxAxDHARCjAlDa0xNYiOkTYP_tE2gAcAN4AIABzAGIAfcKkgEFMC44LjGYAQCgAQKgAQGqAQdnd3Mtd2l6wAEB&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwjJjPL_gvvqAhWTNKYKHaurBRMQ4dUDCAw&uact=5), [writing articles tips](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C5CHFA_enUS706US706&sxsrf=ALeKk01zkGFs2kziAafweKAqmKlGNljsDA%3A1596320216327&ei=2OklX53QE4mkmAXd0J3ICA&q=writing%20articles%20tips&oq=writing%20arti%20tips&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAxgAMgYIABAHEB4yBggAEAcQHjIGCAAQBxAeMggIABAIEAcQHjIICAAQCBAHEB4yCAgAEAgQBxAeMggIABAIEAcQHjIICAAQCBAHEB4yCAgAEAgQBxAeMggIABAIEAcQHjoECAAQRzoECCMQJzoICAAQBxAKEB46AggAUO6PAVjYmQFgvqIBaABwBHgAgAGXAYgB2QWSAQMwLjWYAQCgAQGqAQdnd3Mtd2l6wAEB&sclient=psy-ab), [writing post tips](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C5CHFA_enUS706US706&sxsrf=ALeKk00d2GskMvzQ8vlnAKr-T5vgbOUloQ%3A1596320238029&ei=7uklX4qtAeHRmAWvuomQDw&q=writing%20post%20tips&oq=writing%20post%20tips&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzIICAAQCBAHEB4yCAgAEAgQBxAeMggIABAIEAcQHjIICAAQCBAHEB4yCAgAEAgQBxAeMggIABAIEAcQHjIICAAQCBAHEB4yCAgAEAgQBxAeMggIABAIEAcQHjIICAAQCBAHEB46BAgAEEc6BQghEKABOgQIIxAnOgYIABAWEB46BAgAEB46BggAEAUQHjoGCAAQCBAeUJWgAli4rAJgx68CaAFwBXgAgAGqAYgB9gSSAQMwLjSYAQCgAQKgAQGqAQdnd3Mtd2l6wAEB&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwiK3PClhPvqAhXhKKYKHS9dAvIQ4dUDCAw&uact=5), etc.

Consider the following two sentences.

> the author **did a bit of googling** and ...

> the author **googled a few times** and ...

I guess both of them pretty much mean the same thing and the former sounds more colloquial.

Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 1):

"Googling" refers to the act of using Google and does not reference discrete searches.
"Google" to refer to discrete searches is unnecessarily unweildy unless you're saying "I googled [search term]".

Answer (score 0):

No.

"The author googled a few times" sounds both incomplete and slightly incorrect to my ear. You *Google [something specific]*, and it doesn't make sense to do it multiple times.

But to "do a bit of Googling" implies that you're going through the process with a few different search terms, or clicking through several results to gather information.

Answer (score 0):

- googled his subject a few times over several days

versus

- do a bit of googling to find some information he needed

= that's like: do a bit of swimming

if you use google as an active verb, it requires a direct object.

They don't these sentences necessarily mean the same thing at all.

- I did a bit of cooking today.
- I cooked my favorite dish today.

**Are those the exact same thing?** No, they are not.

To do a bit of [some activity] is idiomatic usage in English.

- He did a bit of cooking in his younger years but gave it up in his forties.

It usually refers to doing some activity casually and is a typical spoken idiom.

People do a bit of this or that in speech at lot. It is not usually written as it sounds conversational and, indeed, is used in conversations unless one is telling a story.